# How to do this normalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This is a chain of transformations representing the process of converting the coordinates of a 3D point in the world coordinate frame to 2D image in the image coordinate frame.

How to do the normalization when the focal length $f$ is known?

> To summarize, using the above notation, the overall geometric model for an ideal camera can be described as
> $$\lambda\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1
> \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}f&0&0\\0&f&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}R&&T\\\\0&&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X_0\\Y_0\\Z_0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
> or in matrix form,
> $$\lambda\boldsymbol x=K_f\Pi_0\boldsymbol X=K_f\Pi_0g\boldsymbol X_0$$
> If the focal length $f$ is known and hence can be normalized to $1$ , this model

Comment: Please replace the image of text by actual text to make this question more accessible. Also please include a reference to where this is taken from. There is a lot of context missing here.

Comment: I'm not sure the question can be answered without additional context.

Answer (score 1):

If the focal length is known, then we can simply multiply both sides of the equation by
$$
K_f^{-1} = \pmatrix{f&0&0\\ 0&f&0\\ 0&0&1}^{-1}
$$
To get an equation involving
$$
\pmatrix{\tilde x\\ \tilde y \\ 1} = \pmatrix{f&0&0\\ 0&f&0\\ 0&0&1}^{-1} \pmatrix{x\\ y\\ 1} = \pmatrix{x/f \\ y/f \\ 1}.
$$
In particular, we have $\lambda \tilde {\mathbf x} = \Pi_0 \mathbf X$.

I believe that "normalization" in this case means using $\tilde x, \tilde y$ instead of $x,y$.